# Non-linear system of ODEs with positive functions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I would like to solve this non-linear system of ODEs, but I need to tell Mathematica to consider y[t] and x[t] to be always positive.
How can I do?

```
   system = {
              t*y'[t] + 3*y[t] == -y[t]/Sqrt[x[t]+y[t]],
              t*x'[t] + 4*x[t] == y[t]/Sqrt[x[t]+y[t]],
              y[1]==1,
              x[1]==0
            };
s = NDSolve[system, {x, y}, {a, 1, 1000}]
```

**Update**

I've tried the method of Alexei Boulbitch and it works fine.

However, if I slightly modify the equations above by multiplying both the r.h.s with a constant `const=10^9`, I obtain the following error message:
[image]

I don't understand what's the problem.

The same issue comes out if I choose a very high initial condition for `y[1]`, such as `y[1]=10^32` or higher.

I would like to include both these add-ons at once, how can I handle these problems?

Comment: What do you mean by "tell Mathematica to consider y[t] and x[t] to be always positive"? If you want `NDSolve` to stop when `x` and `y` is almost `0`, check document of `WhenEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:
First, let us define your system as you did, but shift the initial condition a bit from zero. Otherwise, it gives rise to a singularity:

```
system = {t*y'[t] + 3*y[t] == -y[t]/Sqrt[x[t] + y[t]], 
   t*x'[t] + 4*x[t] == y[t]/Sqrt[x[t] + y[t]], y[1] == 1, 
   x[1] == 0.001};
```

Now, let us replace variables such that `x(t)=φ[t]^2` and  `y[t]=ψ[t]^2`. Like this, the variables  `x` and `y`are always non-negative. And then let us rewrite the initial conditions in terms of the new variables, `φ[t]` and `ψ[t]`:

```
system2 = ReplacePart[system /. {x -> (φ[#]^2 &), 
y -> (ψ[#]^2 &)}, {{3, 1} -> ψ[1], {4} -> φ[1] == Sqrt[0.001]}]
```

[image]

Now, let us solve it:

```
{nds1, nds2} = NDSolveValue[system2, {φ, ψ}, {t, 1, 10}]
```

and plot `x(t)=φ[t]^2` and  `y[t]=ψ[t]^2`:

```
 Plot[{nds1[t]^2, nds2[t]^2}, {t, 1, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
     PlotRange -> {0, 0.12}, AxesLabel -> {Style["t", Italic, 16], 
       Row[{Style["x(t), ", Red, Italic, 16], Style["y(t)", Blue, Italic, 16]}]}]
```

which returns the following:

[image]

Another possibility would be to replace x and y by exponents, as follows:

```
system2 = 
 ReplacePart[system /. {x -> (Exp[φ[#]] &), 
    y -> (Exp[ψ[#]] &)}, {{3} -> ψ[1] == 0, {4} -> φ[1] == Log[0.001]}]
```

The rest is exactly as in the previous case, and the resulting plot

```
Plot[{Exp[nds1[t]], Exp[nds2[t]]}, {t, 1, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.12}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["t", Italic, 16], 
   Row[{Style["x(t), ", Red, Italic, 16], 
     Style["y(t)", Blue, Italic, 16]}]}]
```

looks the same.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you so much! Why in this line, `system2 = ReplacePart[system /. {x -> (φ[#]^2 &), 
y -> (ψ[#]^2 &)}, {{3, 1} -> ψ[1], {4} -> φ[1] == Sqrt[0.001]}]`, do you only set `φ[1]` and why do you use `Sqrt[]`? Shouldn't it be `φ[1] == 0.001^2` ?
Indeed, I have tried to put a very high initial condition for `x[1]==10^16`, but it gives the error "NDSolveValue::ndsz: At a == 1.`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected." 
What could be the reason?

Comment: Shouldn't it be φ[1] == 0.001^2 ? No, since here x=φ^2. Therefore, `φ[1]=Sqrt[x[1]]`. But in fact, you are free to invent any nonlinear transformation of your liking, such that it keeps x and y positive.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry... But what about my second question? It doesn't seem to like very high initial conditions

Comment: It is most probably that the initial condition `x[1]==10^16` is much too high. I am not sure, but it seems that this value is on the limit admitted by Mma. I do not see, why do you need that high initial value. Are you sure that it is for x, rather than for y? If you believe that one of these functions contains a singularity, a good idea might be to separate the singularity out explicitly.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I meant y[1], but the problem is there anyway. For simplicity, I have posted a dimensionless version of the ODE I am interested in. I have tried to generalize it by including the huge physical constants. For example, the two add-ons are:
1) A very high initial condition for y[1];
2) a multiplicative constant `const=2*10^9` in front of the two `y[t]/Sqrt[x[t] + y[t]]`.
If I include only the second condition, after `NDSolveValue` I get `NDSolveValue::ndsz: At a == 1., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected`

Comment: Your equation looks, indeed, stiff in the vicinity of `t=0`. Look at the behavior of `y=y(t)` on the plot. So, it seems that there is nothing to do with this fact, except for not coming to close to `t=0`. If you, however, need to study its behavior close to `t=0`, one way is to represent `y(t)=h(t)*g(t)` where `h(t)` is a singular and `g(t)` - a regular functions. And then try to guess an explicit singular form of `h(t)` and to reformulate the equations in terms of `g(t)`.

Comment: Continuation: You need to find such `h(t)` as to remove the stiffness. As a first guess I would try `h(t)=t^(-a) ` and play with different values of `a>0`. With luck you may find a good function `h(t)`. May take time though.

Comment: Continuation 2: You may look up an example of such an approach in the book Landau and Lifshitz, Quantum Mechanics non-relativistic theory, Second edition, Pergamon Press, Oxford, 1965), p. 102, how they pass form Eq. (32.8) to (32.10).  Have a look at the boundary condition Eq. (32.11) which became non-singular after the transform. Have fun!